# How to cache batches of IDs "locally" in a serverless environment?

Tags: database, architecture, locking, serverless, distributed

Traditionally, in a non-serverless environment, I would have the following system. Say I have a custom ID generation protocol for all my models. Say I also have 20 servers scattered around. I give each server a slice of IDs to work with off the whole stack of IDs. When they are done or the server goes down, it returns the IDs back to the system so they don't get wasted. The reason for sending each server a batch of IDs is so that every time a new record is created you don't need to fetch from a central ID server to get the next ID. Instead they have a local set they can work with freely.

How would you do this sort of thing in a serverless system? I am deploying to Vercel and wondering what the appropriate architecture might be for such an ID batching system. There are other use cases for needed a persistent copy of data in a local server, so if you don't like the ID example just imagine another sort of system. How do you solve this optimization problem in a serverless environment?

Comment: Is it a serverless system that needs to consume the ID service (which can be anything), or does the ID service have to be implemented as serverless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serverless is an approach.  Like all such things (solutions), it should be matched to the problem - not the other way around.  Is this simply a case where serverless is a good solution choice for dealing with 80% of your problem, and that all you need to do is choose something appropriate to deal to the other 20%?

Assuming you have the freedom to do this, can't you just have the serverless parts of the solution consume non-serverless services - e.g. an ID Service?

Separately to this, caching comes to mind - just the general idea of having some data close by which might be mastered somewhere else.  Caching patterns like Write Behind would allow you to work with local copies (i.e. immediate consumption) whilst farming out the cache-master communication.